# Azure devops pipelines running on Self hosted agent - MSAL module

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-ad-msal

I am using azure devops to perform some tasks on Azure AD. I have prepared powershell script for authenticate to MS graph. I am using Azure devops pipelines, script files are stored on azure devops repo. I am using self hosted agent, its Windows Server 2019, all required modules, MSAL, Graph are installed. I am testing my script locally from OS and it works fine. When I am running azure devop pipeline am facing following error `Get-MsalToken : The term 'Get-MsalToken' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable  program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try`". I am using Powershell task in my pipeline.

Comment: If any additional details required please let me know. Its simple ps script containing get-msaltoken command let.

Comment: That error always means the required library is not installed. Are you certain that this library is installed on the slef hosted agent? https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSAL.PS/4.5.1.1

Comment: Msal module installed on self hosted agent. As I mentioned script works fine when I run it directly from hosted agent vm os.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Powershell Core on my self hosted agent. In Azure devops pipelines, Powershell task options, I selected option Advanced/Use Powershell Core. I tested my pipeline, all works as expected.

[image]

Comment: Another DevOps powershell doco black hole.... thanks for returning with your answer.